# Passing a Stack of Arrays in a Bundle

Tags: android, arrays, save, stack, bundle

Does anyone one how to put a Stack of Integer Arrays into a bundle so I can pull them out and restore the Stack again. I've tried it like this however it does not work.

Save Stack of Arrays in Bundle:

```
public Bundle returnBreakStackContents() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        int count = breaksStack.size();//Count gives the Bundle Entry A Unique Key
        bundle.putInt("breakStackSize",count);
        while (!breaksStack.empty()) {
            //Get Break Array From Stack
            Integer[] a = breaksStack.pop();
            //Convert To List
            List b = Arrays.asList(a);
            //Convert To ArrayList
            ArrayList c = new ArrayList();
            c.addAll(b);
            //Save Break to the Bundle with a Unique Key
            bundle.putIntegerArrayList("breakArray" + count, c);
            count--;
        }
        return bundle;
    }
```

Pull Arrays from the bundle and restore the Stack again:

```
Bundle newBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle("breakStack");
            if (newBundle != null) {
                int count = newBundle.getInt("breakStackSize");
                Toast.makeText(this,"Number of Breaks: " + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                while (count > 0) {
                    ArrayList a = newBundle.getIntegerArrayList("breakArray" + count);
                    Integer[] b = new Integer[a.size()];
                    a.toArray(b);
                    bAdapter.getBreaksStack().push(b);
                    count--;
                }
            }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I seem to be getting an Empty Stack Exception. However, it does seem like the objects are going into the stack as I have Logged the Stack.size() being greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

**[java.util.Stack](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Stack.html)** extends **java.util.Vector**, and **[java.util.Vector](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Vector.html)** implements Serializable. So it can be put into Bundle directly.

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.Stack;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private Stack<Integer> mStack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mStack = (Stack) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("stack");
            Log.d(TAG, "Loaded stack from the saved state");
        }
        if (mStack == null) {
            mStack = new Stack<Integer>();
            mStack.add(1);
            mStack.add(2);
            mStack.add(3);
            mStack.add(4);
            Log.d(TAG, "Created new stack");
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "mStack=" + mStack);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("stack", mStack);
    }
}
```